# How to center singlelined TextView between two small images? (using ConstraintLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a slightly weird design task for an Android app to do. My team lead is kinda strict: they want to achieve it using ConstraintLayout only. I need to place the `TextView` with *android:singleLine="true"* attribute between two small images so that it would satisfy two conditions:

- if text is small then it'll be in the center:
  [image]
- if text is big enough then it'll be trimmed and images are still fully visible:
  [image]

I've tried but couldn't figure out how to do this layout. You can see screenshots above.

I have tried for some time, played with attributes with `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_left"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/centered_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/red" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/centered_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="some weird message" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_right"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/centered_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/red" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but I coudn't do it with satisfaction of both design conditions - short and long text.

Could you help me, guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to place the three views into a `packed` horizontal chain. You will then constrain the width of the *TextView*. The following shows these changes:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_left"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/centered_text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centered_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/message" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_right"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/centered_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you, @Cheticamp, I missed `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"` and `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`; you've helped me a lot!